# How to list the hard drive backplanes on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive

I have a Ubuntu server with 9 backplanes. Each backplane can have 5 hard drives (45 in total). I plugged in 45 hard drives, and a quick `ls /dev/sd*` shows only 43 drives (other than  the boot drive). Is there a quick way to find out which two hard drives are bust?

The back planes are wired in a special order, so that if all the hard drives were working, I know exactly which slot is sdb, sdc and so on. I can list the serial numbers of the hard drives using `smartctl -a /dev/sdb | grep Serial` for each drive, and then match them physically by looking at the drives. But I was hoping that there will be an easy way to find it out!

Comment: Exercise them and check the activity LEDs?

Comment: Oh yea... I could have done that. Although the LEDs are not that visible in this particular, but I could have tried. By the way I found the two bust drives. The strange thing is, they were rotating and when I pulled them out, I saw some exception on the screen. But anyways, they didn't work on another server either.